# How to uncheck a group of checkbox in JQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm trying to keep either **All** and a group of checkboxes **(1, 2, 3)** unchecked. For example, when **All** is unchecked and **1** is checked, if I click **All**, **1** should be unchecked, and vice versa.

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" class="selectAll" />  All  <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkuser" class="cb_box "  />  1
<input type="checkbox" name="checkuser" class="cb_box "  />  2
<input type="checkbox" name="checkuser" class="cb_box "  />  3
```

I tried in this way but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

```
$(function () {
 $('.selectAll').click(function () {
   $('input[name=checkuser]').attr('unchecked', $(this).attr('checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

### Use this approach

Function `prop` along with event `change`

```
$('input[name="checkuser"]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.selectAll').change(function() {
      $('input[name="checkuser"]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkAll" class="selectAll" /> All <br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkuser" class="cb_box " /> 1
<input type="checkbox" name="checkuser" class="cb_box " /> 2
<input type="checkbox" name="checkuser" class="cb_box " /> 3
```

## Resource

- [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.selectAll').click(function(){
     $(':checkbox.cb_box').prop('checked', this.checked);    
});
```